# How to search two word in Vim not using "/"?

Tags: vim

I want to custom a macro in vim include a function to search a group of words.
Is it possible?

i.e.

```
The input values can't be empty. (1)
    ^
The input value is five.(2)
    ^
The input values is unknown.(3)
    ^
```

The cursor is in (1). I want to search "input values".
Error search: "input value" at (2).
Expected : The cursor is pointer to "input values" at (3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if I understand you right, you want something like the `*` / `#` commands, but not for the current word, but for more / different text?!

Several plugins extend the `*` / `#` commands to *visual mode*. With them, you can select the two words (`input values`) and then search for them via `v2e*`). One such plugin is my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320), which also offers additional features. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.) The [visualstar.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2944) provides just that single feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
nnoremap \g v2e:call VisualSearch()<CR>

function! VisualSearch() range
    let l:saved_reg = @"
    execute "normal! vgvy"
    let l:pattern = escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]')
    let l:pattern = substitute(l:pattern, "\n$", "", "")
    execute "normal /" . l:pattern . "^M"
endfunction
```

`v2e`will choose two words(only your cursor is on the begin of the first word ) in visual mode;

then `:call VisualSearch()<CR>` , call the function `VisualSearch`;

`VisualSearch`  will search words you select in visual mode

it works for me.

Comment: could you explain what is "vgvy"?